# slick 3 auto-generated - default value (timestamp) column, how to define a Rep[Date] function

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick, slick-3.0

I have the following postgres column definition:

```
record_time TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT now()
```

How would I map it to slick? Please take into account that I wish to map the default value generated by the `now()` function

i.e:

```
def recordTimestamp: Rep[Date] = column[Date]("record_time", ...???...)
```

Should any extra definition go where the `...???...` is currently located?

**EDIT (1)**

I do not want to use

```
column[Date]("record_time", O.Default(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))) // or some such applicative generation of the date column value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is not supported yet. 
Here is issue: https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/214

Answer (score 4):

I found a blog explaining that you can use the following:

```
// slick 3
import slick.profile.SqlProfile.ColumnOption.SqlType
def created = column[Timestamp]("created", SqlType("timestamp not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"))

// slick 3
def createdAt = column[Timestamp]("createdAt", O.NotNull, O.DBType("timestamp default now()"))
```

see: http://queirozf.com/entries/scala-slick-dealing-with-datetime-timestamp-attributes

Comment: Referring to the blog, it was for slick2 though. The slick3 way, again from the blog, is: `import slick.profile.SqlProfile.ColumnOption.SqlType`
  `def created = column[Timestamp]("created", SqlType("timestamp not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"))`

Answer (score 2):

**Slick 3 Example**

```
import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._
import slick.lifted._
import java.sql.{Date, Timestamp}

/** A representation of the message decorated for Slick persistence
  * created_date should always be null on insert operations.
  * It is set at the database level to ensure time syncronicity
  * Id is the Twitter snowflake id. All columns NotNull unless declared as Option
  * */
class RawMessages(tag: Tag) extends Table[(String, Option[String], Timestamp)](tag, Some("rti"), "RawMessages") {
  def id = column[String]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
  def MessageString = column[Option[String]]("MessageString")
  def CreatedDate = column[Timestamp]("CreatedDate", O.SqlType("timestamp default now()"))
  def * = (id, MessageString, CreatedDate)
}
```

Comment: Awesome, is it possible to do for mapped tables?

Comment: If it is defined as a table in PostgreSQL, yes. If it is a view you may need something like 
`slick.jdbc.meta.MTable.getTables(None, None, None, Some(Seq("VIEW","TABLE")))`

The example above [is from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28077228/scala-slick-database-views)